# fbconnect iphone : i want to login every time. how to do that?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, fbconnect

i am using fbconnect in my iphone application to post on my wall. i want to login every time. how to do that ?

currently if i login to facebook in my application once. it does not asks me for login next time... how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works showing the FBDialog everytime ...

```
self.session = [FBSession sessionForApplication:kAPIKey secret:kApplicationSecret delegate:self];
FBLoginDialog* dialog = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] initWithSession:session] autorelease];
    [dialog show];
```

Or you can just logout everytime the user leaves the app:

```
[session logout];
```

Answer (score 0):

Call resume on your session object.

```
[session resume];
```